# Executing batch file in the remote machines using powershell as a background job

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

All I am trying to do is to execute a batch file in remote machines as a job.I have batch file located in all machines inside `C:\Users\temp` folder.Here is my code
`$batFile = "test.bat"
foreach($m in $machine)
{
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $m -ScriptBlock{param($batFile) & cmd.exe /c    "C:\Users\temp\$batFile"} -Authentication negotiate -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $batFile -AsJob
}`

But I keep getting

> The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script
>   block, or a CommandInfo object

I tried using `$using:batFile` inside ScriptBlock as well with no success. Can anyone suggest me what I might be doing wrong? I am using powershell version 4.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, it works for me invoking a .bat on my local computer `Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { param($bat) & cmd.exe /c "d:\$bat"} -ArgumentList 't.bat' -AsJob` and it works with `& $bat` and with `cmd $bat` variations. What if you do `-ScriptBlock{param($batFile) cmd.exe /c    "C:\Users\temp\$batFile"}` without the `&` ?

Comment: This issue is driving me crazy. Is there any alternative to using invoke-command? If I do start-job, I don't see the issue but when I pass the computername inside scriptblock, batch file thinks I am passing the computername as the parameter to the batch file...Start-Job -ScriptBlock{cd "C:\Users\temp";cmd.exe /c; & "C:\Users\temp\test.bat" -ComputerName $machineName}

Comment: Again, what if you do `-ScriptBlock{param($batFile) cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\temp\$batFile"}` without the & ? What expression are you getting after `&` which causes it to error?

Comment: Still the same error --"the expression after &" and I amn't even using & in the code based on your suggestion. Is "invoke-command" interpreted as "&"?

Comment: I can't imagine what's happening. `Get-Help about_operators` - `&` is the 'Call operator' or the 'invocation operator', it's not an alias for Invoke-Command. What is in your test.bat script?

Answer (score 0):

do a trace on that,

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $m -ScriptBlock{param($batFile) Trace-Command NativeCommandParameterBinder -Expression { & cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\temp\$batFile"}} -Authentication negotiate -Credential  $cred -ArgumentList $batFile -AsJob
```

and Try using `Invoke-Expression` as a workaround instead of `&`

```
invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c 'C:\Users\temp\$batFile'"
```

Regards,

Kvprasoon